# Mobile devices scroll too far (into white space)

Tags: css, mobile, scroll

this is my first question on here. I found similar issues but just can't find out where exactly my mistake is.

Its about the mobile version of 
http://www.so-na.com/mnh2016/test/

When visiting the page using certain mobile/touch devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, iPhone 4) it is possible to scroll horizontally and into some white space. This is not intended. I want the content to be 100% wide, with no white space on the sides.

I'm just so stressed out by this project I can't see what I'm missing. Please help!

Comment: Try scrolling in other websites, I'm guessing this is a browser feature and not related to your specific site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting overflow on the html as well as the body (as you have done already).

```
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I haven't tested this on a device yet but have a look.

Comment: oooh...thanks! hiding the overflow on html-tag alone didn't help, but you pointed me to the right direction :) 

I had to add "overflow-x: hidden;" on a certain div - that seemed to fix it.